# How to request route name instead of path when the path is true

Tags: laravel, routes

The following code work just fine but I'd like to know how to implement the same by requesting route name instead of path.

```
   <nav id="navbar">
       <ul>
            <li><a href="{{ route('index') }}" class="{{ Request::path()=== '/' ? 'route-link' : 
                  ''}}">Home</a>
            </li>
      </ul>

   </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are methods for checking this:

```
Request::routeIs('your route name')
```

If you don't have that:

```
Request::route()->named('your route name')
```

Both of these would accept a route name, a string pattern or an array of strings being route names or patterns.

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Requests - Inspecting the Request Path / Route](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#inspecting-the-request-path) `routeIs`